# Usage of: "What is certain is that...." common English?

Tags: phrases, what, clefts, what-clefts

Can you confirm the following expression is used in common and formal cases?

> "What is certain is that..."

As a native German, studying academic English, it sounds slightly strange. May I ask for your confirmation? Is a comma needed?

Comment: It’s a bit stilted; it’s a phrase you’d see in speeches by politicians or articles by pundits. It’s not “common” in terms of frequency, but it’s “common” in terms of being a bit hackneyed. It’s a little flourish added to certain kinds of utterance.

Comment: I heard another phrase like this one: "We are here to help. What the others are here for ? I don't know." So the buildung of a question "what is / What they...ect." is in the focus of my question.

Comment: Better to reframe you question to be broader, then. You can [edit] it directly from that link.

Comment: @Shoe. You are probably right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is certain is that . . ..

As a concluding thought in a line of reasoning, which is characterized by the existence of an *uncertainty* (or, uncertainties), the above phrase would be appropriate and not as stilted if its second word (viz., is) is emphasized by being italicized.

> What ***is*** certain is that . . .."

So for example, if the line of reasoning goes as follows,

> While we are uncertain about what course to take, what ***is*** certain is that we need to make a decision now, before we run out of time,

then the phrase makes perfect sense. It also provides balance to the line of reasoning and is a good substitute for the locution

> On the one hand . . ., but on the other hand . . ..

Answer (score 4):

This is not an uncommon construction in academic English. For example:

> - What is certain is that more research is needed to improve modeling of the climate in the Great Lakes region.
> - What is certain is that a monetary value can only be applied to natural capital if it is considered on a smaller scale.
> - What is certain is that prolonged exposure to unwanted noise at any level can be a source of great stress.

Such constructions are called [pseudo-clefts](http://www.grammaring.com/pseudo-cleft-sentences),  where the *what* clause functions as the subject followed by the simple predicate (the copula *is*). Subjects should not be separated from their predicates by a comma.